# Can I make the jQuery datepicker display more year when using the changeYear option?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jQuery datepicker in an application which will be used, among other things, to insert and update birth dates of employees. I find it cumbersome to have to click several times in order to get to the 70's and 80', decades in which many employees are born in. Is there a way to access these 'further' years in less clicks?
This is what my datepicker looks like

```
$("#DateOpened").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    maxDate: "+0D",
    showAnim: 'slide',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    'setDate': new Date(),
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#DateClosed").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `yearRange` option to increase the size of the year drop-down.

```
yearRange: "c-30:+0"
```

will allow selecting a year after 1983 in one click, and the 70's in 2 clicks.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/kGjdL/341/)

However, this isn't a good UI. When the user first clicks on the menu, it's not obvious that they can go back more than 30 years by first selecting an old year and then clicking on the menu again. You can use `c-100:+0` to allow the menu to contain 100 years, hopefully this wil be enough for most users.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, then yes it is possible using `minDate` and `maxDate` options.  Here you can set the year that has to be shown.

```
changeYear: true,
minDate: '-1Y',  //decrease 1 year from current year
maxDate: '+2Y'   //increase 2 from current year
```

`Y` represent year.

[image]

This is one shortest way to reach the year soon.

Comment: No, that's not what I was looking for. The `minDate` and `maxDate` options are used to restrict dates. I want to get to the 70's faster, in less clicks. Try it here http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year 
You will have to click several times.

Comment: It looks as if it is impossible, though.

Comment: You can use the `yearRange` option to control the size of the year drop-down. It defaults to 10 years in each direction, you can increase it to allow reaching older dates in fewer clicks.

Comment: @Goran_Mandic I agree.  But I guess instead of picking the year, how about entering the year replacing dropdown with textbox.  This need a lot of work.  however lets try and also search for any plugins available.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's it. Thank you. Post your comment as an answer, please.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan according to my PM, this is bad user experience. It is not my desicion.

Comment: @Goran_Mandic thought that would be easy of navigation, `yearRange`I have used but it didn't showed up in my mind.  Will be deleting my answer.